# How to store (x,y) coordinates within a queue in C

Tags: c, queue, coordinates, breadth-first-search

I am doing a breadth first search algorithim and I am having trouble storing the starting coordinates within my Queue implementation as (x,y) as one element within the queue.

I have used arrays and structs but it keeps entering in each int value as two separated queue elements. Is there a way to store both elements as one queue?

```
struct queue {
int items[SIZE];
int front;
int rear;
};

struct queue* createQueue();

 struct queue* createQueue() {
    struct queue* q = malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
    q->front = -1;
    q->rear = -1;
    return q;
}

struct queue* q = createQueue();  
int c[2] = {2,3};

enqueue(q, c);
enqueue(q, 6);
printQueue(q);

void enqueue(struct queue* q, int value){
    if(q->rear == SIZE-1)
        printf("\nQueue is Full!!");
    else {
        if(q->front == -1)
            q->front = 0;
        q->rear++;
        q->items[q->rear] = value;
    }
}
```

> Expected:
>
> Queue Contains:
>   (2,3), 6

Comment: Note that in `enqueue(q, c);` you're giving a parameter of type `int [2]` while in the signature it should take an `int`

Comment: yeah, I also tried to pass it as an array but that also means passing its values as separated elements.

Comment: If you want to add all the elements of an array in the queue in a single call then you better rewrite a new function like `enqueue_all` which takes an array and then call the `enqueue` on each element of the array.

Comment: or change the data inside the `struct queue` to `int *elements`

Comment: How do you mean? Becuase I tried using a for loop to enqueu each element in the array but it still gives me them as seperated queue elements as opposed to just one.

Comment: This question is unclear to me. Are you trying to implement a queue that can hold two data types, i.e. int-pairs and single ints?

Comment: How does your `struct queue` look?

Comment: Can you show your `struct queue` and `createQueue()` function?

Comment: Okay, I added it.

Comment: @dpalacios You still don't show us how `struct queue` is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you want a queue where you can store both items that represents integer pairs (aka `x,y`) and items that represents a single integer.

That is not possible with the queue you define:

```
struct queue {
    int items[SIZE];  <--- each item can only hold a single integer! Not a pair of integers
    int front;
    int rear;
};
```

So you need another data structure.

Further, your `enqueue` function are called with two different types of arguments

```
int c[2] = {2,3};
enqueue(q, c);     <--- here the argument is a int-pointer (because c decays into int-pointer)
enqueue(q, 6);     <--- here the argument is a integer
```

That is not allowed in C. So you need two different functions. One for pairs and one for integers.

There are many different ways to implement what you ask for. Below is one example that uses a `struct dataitem` to store the actual data. The `size` field is used to check if the stored data is a pair or just a single integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 8

struct dataitem
{
  int size;     // Will be 2 for pairs and 1 for single integers
  int data[2];
};

struct queue {
  struct dataitem items[SIZE];
  int front;
  int rear;
};


struct queue* createQueue() {
  struct queue* q = malloc(sizeof *q);
  q->front = 0;
  q->rear = 0;
  return q;
}

int full(struct queue* q)
{
  return (((q->rear + 1) % SIZE) == q->front);
}

int empty(struct queue* q)
{
  return (q->rear == q->front);
}

// Add single integer
void enqueue_int(struct queue* q, int value){
  if (full(q))
  {
    printf("\nQueue is Full!!");
    return;
  }

  q->items[q->rear].size = 1;
  q->items[q->rear].data[0] = value;
  q->rear = (q->rear + 1) % SIZE;
}

// Add pair of integers
void enqueue_pair(struct queue* q, int* values){
  if (full(q))
  {
    printf("\nQueue is Full!!");
    return;
  }

  q->items[q->rear].size = 2;
  q->items[q->rear].data[0] = values[0];
  q->items[q->rear].data[1] = values[1];
  q->rear = (q->rear + 1) % SIZE;
}

void printQueue(struct queue* q)
{
  int tmp = q->front;
  printf("Queue Contains: ");
  int flag = 0;
  while(tmp != q->rear)
  {
    if (flag) printf(", ");
    flag = 1;
    if (q->items[tmp].size > 1)
    {
      printf("(%d,%d)", q->items[tmp].data[0], q->items[tmp].data[1]);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("%d", q->items[tmp].data[0]);
    }
    tmp = (tmp + 1) % SIZE;
  }
  printf("\n");
}

struct dataitem dequeue(struct queue* q)
{
    struct dataitem res;
    if (empty(q))
    {
        res.size = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        res = q->items[q->front];
        q->front = (q->front + 1) % SIZE;
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{
  int c[2] = {2,3};
  struct queue* q = createQueue();
  enqueue_pair(q, c);
  enqueue_int(q, 6);
  printQueue(q);

  struct dataitem data;
  for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
  {
    data = dequeue(q);
    if (data.size == 0)
    {
      printf("queue was empty\n");
    }
    else if (data.size == 1)
    {
      printf("queue had integer %d\n", data.data[0]);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("queue had pair (%d,%d)\n", data.data[0], data.data[1]);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works beautifully. What if I wanted to dequeue an element?  Does it work the same way as if I were dequeing a single integer?

Comment: @dpalacios In order to deque you'll have to return a `struct dataitem` and then look at the `size` to see if it is a pair or a single integer

Comment: @dpalacios I have added a `dequeue` example (and fixed a bug in the first answer)

Comment: note that `int data[2]` of `struct dataitem` may become a union to improve readability. You can define a `xy_t` representing the coordinates (`struct xy_t { int x, int y}`) and then define `data` as `union { struct xy_t xy; int value}`

Comment: @Koldar As I wrote in the answer: "There are many different ways to implement what you ask for." And yes - a tagged union is also a way to go...